# Trouble applying my function to more than one text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am completely new to jquery and am trying to figure out how to apply my function to more than one textbox, I ultimately need to hook it up to another function similar to the one I have, but I just cannot figure out how to hook them both up so they do not allow certain inputs.  Any advice on this is much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$("#textBox").keypress(function (e)  //the function will check the  textbox
{ 


  if( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57))
  {
    return false;
  } 
});





});
</script>

</script>

</head>
<body>

<font face='courier'>
Numbers Only : <input type="text" id="textBox" /><br/>
Letters Only : <input type="text" id="textBox2" />

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you want? Your `keypress` function to apply to both textboxes? Or a different `keypress` function for each textbox? In any case, I think looking at the jQuery selector docs could be very helpful: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Notice that you´re closing your script tag twice but are not closing the font tag.

Comment: Stefan, I just caught my mismatched tags soon after posting this thanks thoo, and James yes I want to eventually hook up a very similar function which will allow letters only in the same manner which the first text box limits input to only digits.

Comment: @Don Rigatone I do not want to be self serving, but do not forget to select the answer you accepted as the response. You have a couple of good answer below. Find the one that works for you and click the check outline. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that

```
$("#textBox,#textBox2").keypress();
```

The example provided select only one textarea. You are using a specific id that is only used once.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Thanks, I am still just getting used to the jquery syntax but that worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Just use a class selector, or an attribute selector:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function(e) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use class attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="myclass" id="textBox" />
<input type="text" class="myclass" id="textBox2" />
```

In your javascript

```
 $(".myclass").keypress(function (e)  //the function will check the  textbox
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply the function to all `input type="text"` elements:

Change:

```
$("#textBox").keypress(function (e)  //the function will check the  textbox
```

To:

```
$(":text").keypress(function (e)  //the function will check the  textbox
```

If you only want it to apply to certain text inputs, tag those inputs with class="myClass" and change the jquery line to:

```
$(".myclass").keypress(function (e)  //the function will check the  textbox
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a selector that matches all your textboxes or use a multiple selector.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

I suggest you add a CSS class to all elements you would like to select. That makes it easier to add more elements in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the existing function to both boxes simply by using the CSS-style comma:

```
$("#textBox, #textBox2").keypress(function (e)
```

this (obviously) prevents letters in both boxes.